# Piping oboe.js parsed json to http response object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, oboe.js

I'm using Oboe.js to parse JSON from a Node readStream and I want to send this back to the client requesting it in a memory-efficient manner. Is it possible to pipe data from Oboe's `node` or `path` events to a Node.js HTTP response object, so I can delivered parsed data on the fly to a client rather than collecting it in full and sending it all at once? This is the code I have so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const oboe = require('oboe');
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/download', (req, res) => {

    const jsonDataStream = fs.createReadStream('./citylots.json');

    oboe(jsonDataStream)
        .node('features.*', function(feature) {
           // res.send is non-streaming. how to stream?
            res.send(feature);
        });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`up on port ${ PORT }!`));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question, I think the problem has to do with the fact that `res.send` terminates the response ([docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)). Given that `res` is a writable stream, you can call `res.write` to write a string to the response. You will have to do some additional work to insert commas as well as a starting `[` and `]`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const oboe = require('oboe');
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/download', (req, res) => {

    const jsonDataStream = fs.createReadStream('./citylots.json');

    oboe(jsonDataStream)
        .node('features.*', function(feature) {
          res.write(JSON.stringify(feature));
        });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`up on port ${ PORT }!`));
```

To step back from this though, I want to be sure Oboe is good for your use case. It might be complicating your implementation without much benefit. Is your goal to reduce memory by sending less data to the client? In other words, are you trying to avoid sending all of `citylots.json` and instead want to only send its `features`?

Comment: JuanCaicedo I guess my question is really: does oboe have a stream interface, or do I need to use another library, like highland.js, for that? I want to avoid ever buffering the entire json file in memory all at once. To answer your last question, I had just chosen the features object instead of the entire json for experimentation purposes, there wasn't any specific intention behind it.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is keeping sending data without holding the entire file in memory.

Therefore, you need to use pipe. Pipe will allow you to send the data with chunks